# SESSION var in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

Is it possible to use `$_SESSION[var]` in `INSERT` and `SELECT` statements of mysql as in below

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (id, var1, var2)
            VALUES (NULL, '$_SESSION[var1]', '$_SESSION[var2]')";
mysql_query($query);
die(mysql_error());
```

NOTE: I have `session_start();` at the start of all my pages.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Maybe it can help us answer your question better. What do you need to insert $_SESSIONS for?

Comment: it's a two page submission process, and the second depends on the values from the first set of user input variables, moreso both forms are not on the same page, because the second form will be continued several times as in Number of Students in a class.

Comment: Yes, `$_SESSION` variables are variables like any other. Just use the right name (eg: `$_SESSION` instead of `$_SESSIONS`) and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea to [sanitize your vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before executing queries against them:

```
$var1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['var1']);
$var2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['var2']);

$query = 
    "INSERT INTO table1 (id, var1, var2) " .
    "VALUES (NULL, '" . $var1 . "', '" . $var2 . "')";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note that your last time line of code `die(mysql_error())` will cause the script to stop execution regardless of whether or not an error occured.

Also, you may want to look into [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) for your database interaction.

Comment: Not even sure how to respond. Just the nature of "know nothing about the nature" of the vars is enough to escape to be on the safe side. I've never worked on an app where strings are purposely escaped that had nothing to do with database interaction.

Comment: The reason why I am pointing this is out is because I am tired of seeing code written based on "rules of thumb" rather than actual knowledge. People should understand why they call a function rather than just doing it because they've been told to. Also, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is possibly the ugliest thing I've ever seen. If you want to prevent SQL injection, use PDO and prepared statements, not this.

Comment: Wait, so my solution is being chastised b/c OP opted to use mysql_query vs PDO? I agree with you, I too use PDO when not using ORM (doctrine), but I was just showing the author that they may want to go the extra step to protect their database.

Comment: I removed the downvote, but I still think advice to "sanitize your vars" should be given with further explanation.

Comment: Linked the function description via php.net, hopefully the author takes a look.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In my opinion the best way to specify an array variable in an interpolated string is to put curly brackets around it so that you can utilize single quotes around the array key:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table1 (id, var1, var2)
              VALUES (NULL, '{$_SESSION['var1']}', {$_SESSION['var2']}')";
```

Comment: Yes, I just copied and pasted his code, didn't notice he had the extra S, but I'll fix.

Comment: the extra s wasnt there originally.
When i ran the query i got undefined index for var1 and var2

Comment: session variables are created by making assignment to $_SESSION.  That is the way you work with php sessions.  You can create an array variable named $_SESSIONS if you want, but it will not be a session variable.   You may have other issues with your code -- you only provided a snippet, and we have to assume you have previously assigned values to $_SESSION['var1'] and $_SESSION['var2'].  If that is not working, you have problems we can only guess at.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i'm still getting undefined index, ath the points where SESSION are used.

Comment: I did  thsi on the first page of the form

       $var1 = $_POST['var1'] ;
       $_SESSION['var1'] = $var1;


then on the second page where i needed the sessions after, using it in the mysql query, i got undefined index.

Comment: did you session_start() first in both pages?